# How do I fix my renderflex overflowed by pixels that has a pixel of 19 on the bottom

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:chat_app/components/chat_bubble.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/components/chat_detail_page_appbar.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/models/chat_message.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/models/send_menu_items.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum MessageType{
  Sender,
  Receiver,
}


class ChatDetailPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _ChatDetailPageState createState() => _ChatDetailPageState();
}

class _ChatDetailPageState extends State<ChatDetailPage> {
  List<ChatMessage> chatMessage = [
    ChatMessage(message: "Hi John", type: MessageType.Receiver),
    ChatMessage(message: "Hope you are doin good", type: MessageType.Receiver),
    ChatMessage(message: "Hello Jane, I'm good what about you", type: MessageType.Sender),
    ChatMessage(message: "I'm fine, Working from home", type: MessageType.Receiver),
    ChatMessage(message: "Oh! Nice. Same here man", type: MessageType.Sender),
  ];

  List<SendMenuItems> menuItems = [
    SendMenuItems(text: "Photos & Videos", icons: Icons.image, color: Colors.amber),
    SendMenuItems(text: "Document", icons: Icons.insert_drive_file, color: Colors.blue),
    SendMenuItems(text: "Audio", icons: Icons.music_note, color: Colors.orange),
    SendMenuItems(text: "Location", icons: Icons.location_on, color: Colors.green),
    SendMenuItems(text: "Contact", icons: Icons.person, color: Colors.purple),
  ];

  void showModal(){
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
          color: Color(0xff737373),

          child:Expanded(

            child: Container(

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20),topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
              ),
              child: Column(

                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 16,),

                  Center(
                    child: Container(

                      height: 4,
                      width: 50,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: menuItems.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10),
                        child: ListTile(

                          leading: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              color: menuItems[index].color.shade50,
                            ),
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            child: Icon(menuItems[index].icons,size: 20,color: menuItems[index].color.shade400,),
                          ),
                          title: Text(menuItems[index].text),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: ChatDetailPageAppBar(),
      body: Stack
      (children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: chatMessage.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10),
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ChatBubble(
              chatMessage: chatMessage[index],
            );
            },
         ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container
              (
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16,bottom: 10),
              height: 80,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      showModal();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,size: 21,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 16,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Type message...",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                        border: InputBorder.none
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30,bottom: 50),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Icon(Icons.send,color: Colors.white,),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                elevation: 0,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I am having trouble with due to the fact that the contact icon cannot be shown because renderflex overflowed by pixels that has a pixel of 19 on the bottom I

I try searching from Youtube and tried that methods but still cannot work so how please give your suggestions or guidance on this matter

Comment: where you got this error? or Wrap your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`